# jQuery draggable containment using array is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have this piece of HTML

```
<div id="workflowEditor" class="workflow-editor">

    <div class="node" class="ui-widget" style="top:20px; left:40px;">
        <div class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-state-default">Header test</div>
        <div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">Test Content</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

With this CSS

```
.workflow-editor
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.workflow-editor .node
{
    position: absolute;

    min-width: 64px;
    min-height: 64px;
}
```

Than calling

```
$(".node", "#workflowEditor").draggable({
    containment: [0, 0, 500, 500]
});
```

However, dragging this "node" will allow dragging into negative values; it seems that `draggable` is using the browser's viewport coordinate to limit the bounding box. Is there some way to tell that the coordinates are relative to the draggable's parent?

**Note**: the parent may change position over time.

#### ** Edit ****

the surface where the draggables are located is relative to some other content. Like the CSS specifies, I need it to be `overflow:scroll;`, so if the draggables are dragged outside, then the scrollbars will be displayed. The parent's size is fixed. The problem I'm having is that the draggables can be dragged to the left (or top) of the surface (thus I lose them). I'd like to have a similar behaviour as setting the containment to `"parent"`, but allowing draggables to overflow unto the right/bottom sides of the parent.

Answer (score 5):

calculating  the boundaries of the node and its parent, please check the [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rachit_doshi/FhNtt/3/)
 as per the explanations at [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)

```
var containmentX1 = $(".node").parent().offset().left;
var containmentY1 = $(".node").parent().offset().top;
var containmentX2 =  ($(".node").parent().outerWidth() +  $(".node").parent().offset().left - $('.node').outerWidth())
var containmentY2 = ($(".node").parent().outerHeight() +  $(".node").parent().offset().top - $('.node').outerHeight()) 

$(".node").draggable({
    containment:  [containmentX1, containmentY1, containmentX2, containmentY2]
});
```

Comment: No, it does not : http://jsfiddle.net/FhNtt/1/. As explained, the containment is absolute to the browser view port, *not* the parent element (or even the element itself)

Comment: First, the entire editor is now draggable? This is undesirable. Second, the containment is not the expected one; the expected one is dynamic, not fixed, therefore it cannot be the element, but a dimension. I already tried setting another element inside and giving it a size, but then scrollbars are always visible, which is also not desired. Please, read carafully and suggest appropriate answers from the requirements. Thank you for your efforts, though :)

Comment: What you are proposing is similar to having your very first answer. Read the very last statement of the question : "I'd like to have a similar behaviour as setting the containment to "parent", but allowing draggables to overflow unto the right/bottom sides of the parent." This is what I need. Your solution still does not allow to drag beyound the boundaries (thus overflowing inside the parent). In short, the containment should be relative to the parent `#workflowEditor`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem - I needed to position "boxes" inside a container, allowing them to overflow to the bottom or the right, but not to the left or top. I also had to support varying the container's position.

Unfortunately, I could not find an elegant solution. As you correctly note, setting the containment via a coordinates array will establish document-related metrics, so we have to work with the position of the container relative to the document.

My little hack was to use the "document" position of the container for the top and left limits (I used jQuery `offset` [1], and a *big enough* value for right and bottom. I used the `dragstart` event [2] to re-read and reset the viewport position of the container (which updated the containment box to the current coordinates of the container, via the `options` method [3]).

```
var $containerEl = $('#container'),
    $draggableEl = $('#my-draggable');

$draggableEl.on('dragstart', function (e) {
    $(e.target).draggable('option',
                          'containment',
                          [ $containerEl.offset().left, $containerEl.offset().top, 15000, 15000 ]);
});

$draggableEl.draggable({
    containment: [ $containerEl.offset().left, $containerEl.offset().top, 15000, 15000 ]
});
```

[1] http://api.jquery.com/offset/

[2] http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start

[3] http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-option